# CSS Content Before & After to append characters to HREFs?

Tags: css

I would like to make all my link text to for from average_link to [ AVERAGE_LINK ] .. is this possible with only CSS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not supported completely cross-browsers, but you can do it with the `content` property and the `:before` and `:after` pseudo classes

```
a:before
{
    content: "[";
}

a:after
{
    content: "]";
}
```

You can see support for the attributes here:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
a:link.MyLink {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:link.MyLink :before {
    content: "[";
}
a:link.MyLink :after {
    content: "]";
}
```

However, the last two rules will not work in IE.

Answer (score -2):

No. You can style the text but not change the text with CSS.